# Logstash Sql_Last_value date format seems to irrelevant

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

Hi All i am using logstash to index document from MSSQL server to elasticsearch i using below config to for doing incremental indexing for that i am using using column called modified_date but having problem with dateformat.

**below is my config**

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "D:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/driver/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12-shaded.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://EC2AMAZ-J90JR4A\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=xxxx;"
jdbc_user => "xxx"
jdbc_password => "xxxx"
jdbc_paging_enabled => true
tracking_column => modified_date
use_column_value => true
clean_run => true
tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
statement => "Select pl.policynumber,pl.policyholdername,pl.dob,pl.age,pl.client_address clientaddress,cl.claimnumber,Cl.claimtype,cl.modified_date modified_date,Cl.is_active from policy pl
inner join claim Cl on Cl.policynumber=pl.policynumber where cl.modified_date >:sql_last_value"
}
}
filter {
if [is_active] {
        mutate {    
            add_field => {
                "[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]" => "index"
            }
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "is_active","@version","@timestamp" ]
        }
    } else {
        mutate {    
            add_field => {
                "[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]" => "delete"
            }
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "is_active","@version","@timestamp" ]
        }
} 
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "https://e5a4a4a4de7940d9b12674d62eac9762.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243"
user => "elastic"
password => "xxxxx"
index => "xxxx"
action => "%{[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]}"
document_type => "_doc"
document_id => "%{claimnumber}"

}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Attached screen shot
[image]

Date format seems to be wrong due to that each time it is picking all the documents instead of modified one sould some one provide insight on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove/comment the input parameter `clean_run => true`, this will make `sql_last_value` to be ignored which result every time complete data load.

Adding additional (following) parameter can let you debug and track how the `sql_last_value` generating:

```
last_run_metadata_path => "D:\logstash<version>\jdbc_lastrun\filename"
```

In addition to that following is the typical `input` configuration of `jdbc` with optimal approach ([prepared statement](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_prepared_statements))

```
jdbc {  jdbc_driver_library => "D:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/driver/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12-shaded.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://EC2AMAZ-J90JR4A\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=xxxx;"
        jdbc_user => "xxx"
        jdbc_password => "xxxx"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => true
        statement => "Select pl.policynumber,pl.policyholdername,pl.dob,pl.age,pl.client_address clientaddress,cl.claimnumber,cl.claimtype,cl.modified_date modified_date,cl.is_active from policy pl inner join claim cl on cl.policynumber=pl.policynumber where cl.modified_date > (?)"
        use_prepared_statements => "true"
        prepared_statement_bind_values => [":sql_last_value"]
        prepared_statement_name => "jdbc_input_query1"
        tracking_column => modified_date
        #clean_run => true
        tracking_column_type => "date"
        schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
        last_run_metadata_path => "D:\logstash<version>\jdbc_lastrun\filename"
}
```

Comment: I had an internal loader issue with my JDBC_Driver so i have upgraded my logstash from 7.2.0 to 7.5.2 latest

Comment: After updating the logstash Sql_last_value not working properly for Ex: If i go with version 7.2.0  it's fine '2020-02-05T13:27:09.023' (date updated in file last_run_metadata_path)

Comment: If i go with 7.5.2 latest date updated wrongly for Ex: '2020-02-05 07:14:20.313000000' instead of  '2020-02-05T13:27:09.023' due to this i am unable to do incremental indexing.

Comment: Have opened a topic in discuss.elastic.co on this, kindly check the below link too because i have given a detailed explaination with screenshots still the topic is open

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sql-last-value-date-format-seems-to-be-irrelevant/217790/2

Comment: I am not able to figure out why date is updated wrongly if i upgrade my logstash version

Comment: Found [this at github](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/293) as open issue. you may follow that!

Answer (score 0):

Added config for reference, [After adding jdbc_time_zone](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sql-last-value-date-format-seems-to-be-irrelevant/217790/4) it is working fine. Thanks a lot for your help

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => ""
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://EC2AMAZ-J90JR4A\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=xxxx;"
jdbc_user => "xxxx"
jdbc_password => "xxx"
jdbc_paging_enabled => true
tracking_column => modified_date
use_column_value => true
clean_run => true
tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
statement => "Select* from claim where modified_date >:sql_last_value"
last_run_metadata_path => "D:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\logstash-7.2.0\jdbc_lastrun\jdbc_last_run.txt"
jdbc_default_timezone => "UTC" 
}
}
filter {
mutate {
   remove_field => ["@version","@timestamp"]
 }
}
output {

stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```